# how can I dd ONLY last portion of drive that hasn't already been dev/zero'd

Tags: rhel, dd, zfs, block-device

I regularly dd a drive to erase them for ZFS resilver, when something goes awry with read/write or checksum error, to put the drive back into service. Frequently, removing the partition table at the beginning is not enough for ZFS to ***not*** recognize the drive.

I would like to both remove both partition table at beginning (already know how to do that, that's documented enough), and partition table on end of 3TB drive, and test if this works.  How can I remove the last partition table (gpt) only??

Now to my primary question.
I have already ran `dd` then canceled it at some point (see below), to test if ZFS would no longer recognize it; this wasn't enough -- ZFS still recognizes it and put it right into degraded mode again.

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-35000c50084818db7
^C726443929+0 records in
726443928+0 records out
371939291136 bytes (372 GB) copied, 7997.73 s, 46.5 MB/s
```

So now I just want to seek past the 372GB and dev/zero after that, so that it doesn't waste time, and hard drive life doing the first 372GB AGAIN.

I was thinking something like this, but it didn't work.

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-35000c50084818db7 seek=371G
dd: ‘/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-35000c50084818db7’: cannot seek: Invalid argument
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes (0 B) copied, 0.000238797 s, 0.0 kB/s
```

Looking in the documentation is a real chore.  This page almost looked helpful https://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/Some_dd_examples, but I'm not seeing what I need in there.

Am I simply missing the block size, or what's missing why that doesn't work?  I tried adding `conv=notrunc` to that line above, that didn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `seek` argument to `dd` is the number of output blocks to seek

With no `bs=` or `obs=` in your command, this defaults to 512 bytes

You can see that `726443928` blocks were written

Simplest solution is to use that number in the seek

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-35000c50084818db7 seek=726443928
```

By the way, the documentation you linked to states this quite clearly

> Seek skips over so many **blocks** on the output media before writing

---

Erasing the secondary GPT

The secondary GPT table lives 33 sectors (512 byte sectors) from the end of the disk

So, if `fdisk -l /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-35000c50084818db7` reports

```
Disk /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-35000c50084818db7: 2.73 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
```

Then you subtract 33 from 5860533168  = `5860533135`

And do

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-35000c50084818db7 skip=5860533135
```

Comment: Very good.  I was wondering if it was because `bs`, but i figured it was smart enough to read and use what was already there for that.  ok, so using blocks works.  Nice...

Can someone please add to the answer how i can just grab the last partition table alternatively?

Also, i just didnt know what i was looking for in the docs, to me that may as well have said bytes, instead of blocks, and i didnt realize the number you added to seek was actually blocks until now, i thought it was bytes. :-)  Thanks for pointing that out!!  Thats what i needed.

Comment: what does "how i can just grab the last partition table alternatively?" alternatively to what?

Comment: alternatively to dev/zero the entire remaining drive.... Just dev/zero the part table at end of drive, exclusively, as in my original first question..

Comment: your question is "how can i dd ONLY last portion of drive that hasnt already been dev/zero'd" - which I assumed was the question

Comment: use `gdisk` ... in the expert options there's a `zap GPT data structures and exit` option - seems that's what you may want

Comment: yeah i've used that before, the problem is, sometimes the disks are encrypted, on purchase as refurb, where  gdisk errors. Maybe this will work in this scenario though, when they were already enrolled as members correctly prior to crashing.  Thanks.  I really would like to know how to specify that to dd though, i thought it would be almost as simple as removing the first part table, however i think there is math involved for this one.

Comment: @BrianThomas - I've added info on how to erase the secondary GPT table